# Could not find method implementation() for arguments on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies, gradle-plugin

I`m using Android Studio for Developing Flutter Application. After I install the Kotlin plugin in Android Studion, Application is not working. Then I remove that plugin but it's not working

build.gradle file

```
   buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'

}
```

Terminal

[Error Message in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nciGx.png)

Comment: try invalidate and restart android studio once

Comment: I try It. But it didn't work for me. @ParthPitroda